# Postgres + Django. Оптимизация select запроса с большим offset

Tags: django, postgresql

Имеется таблица с +- 1 млн строк.

Нужно выводить записи постранично (100 записей на странице). Подразумевается, что может быть большой `offset`.

Решение в лоб:

`Table.objects.only('name', 'description', 'serial').order_by('-serial').all()[600000:600100]`

Страничка с таким запросом грузится секунд 10. Какие вообще пути есть решения такой задачи?

P.S. Индекс на `serial` повесил, особо ничего не дало.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю python, но разве вот тут вы:

```
.all()[600000:600100]
```

Не вычитываете вообще всю таблицу, чтобы только на приложении достать диапазон элементов? Выглядит именно так, и тогда стоит ли удивляться медлительности?

---

Но применимо к любой СУБД: чтобы быстро получить страницу не делайте offset. Это неправильная реализация страничной навигации. Помимо той очевидной проблемы, которую вы наблюдаете и которая побудила вас написать вопрос, что offset 600000 limit 100 требует прочитать 600100 строк и выбросить первые 600000, есть так же неудобства для использования такого ужасного способа нарезки на страницы.

Представьте, вы читаете очередную страницу, в это время по какой-то причине удаляется несколько записей на предыдущих страницах. Что вы получите при попытке открыть следующую страницу? Правильно, вы не увидите несколько строк, которые по нумерации offset'а стали считаться предыдущей страницей, хотя вы их никогда не видели. Или несколько строк добавляется на первой странице - и вы видите строки, которые уже встретили на предыдущей странице. Потому что весь offset сместился. Сервис работает медленно, показывает данные которые уже видел на предыдущей странице, проглатывает данные при переходе на страницу. Совершенно дурацкое поведение, которое по какому-то недоразумению называют страничной навигацией.

Правильная, стабильная и предсказуемая как для пользователя так и по производительности реализация страничной навигации заключается в детерминированном (уникальном и не случайном) порядке сортировки, а для получения следующей страницы нужен не эфемерный номер страницы, а сведения о последней показанной строке выборки и запрос "дай следующие 100 записей после такой-то строки".

Например, выводите список в порядке sale_date. Для гарантии порядка результата добавляем `primary key` sale_id в сортировку:

ORDER BY sale_date DESC, sale_id DESC

Для запроса следующей страницы передаём дату и sale_id последней показанной строки на прошлой странице и запрашиваем именно продолжение списка:

```
WHERE (sale_date, sale_id) < (?, ?)
ORDER BY sale_date DESC, sale_id DESC
```

Всё, у нас есть следующая страница. Скорость формирования очередной выборки не падает в зависимости от глубины чтения, эффективно использует индекс и не нервирует пользователя неожиданным поведением.

Хорошее описание есть в англоязычной статье от [Markus Winand](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page)

---

Отдельно глядя на теги хочу заметить:

```
order by -serial limit 10

order by  serial desc limit 10
```

Это две огромные разницы для postgresql. Результат одинаковый, но первый выполняет сортировку по вычисляемому выражению и потому не может выполняться по индексу. Разве только у вас есть индекс именно по `btree((-serial))`. Порядок сортировки лучше задавать предназначенными для того ключевыми словами `ASC` и `DESC`

Comment: "Не вычитываете вообще всю таблицу" - в данном конкретном случае нет, там специальный ленивый QuerySet объект, который преобразует это в sql offset-limit. Тем не менее большие смещения в sql всегда были медленными сами по себе

Comment: Предложенный Вами вариант с пагинацией, когда бы знаем только id последней записи на последней странице мы рассматривали, но при таком раскладе мы можем, получается, сделать пагинацию только взад-вперед и не можем дать пользователю переместиться на, например, 22 страницу.